# Loosing Session and cookies in IE for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, session, cookies

My application is working fine in Chrome. But in IE9 I am loosing session and cookies. `token` is created in current session only but but I am not able to retrieve this IE (chrome works fine).

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["token"] != null)
        {
            var memberIdEncrypted = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["token"].Value;
            var auth = new CustomAuthentication();
            memberId = auth.DecryptToken(memberIdEncrypted);
        }
```

Comment: Is your IE instance configured to accept cookies? You can disable cookies which would in turn, disable the ability to use sessions with cookies.

Comment: Could also be that your IE has _Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed_ enabled, that (apparently) would cause cookies to get deleted too.